# HTTP_PROXY not working

Tags: curl, proxy, redhat

I have a situation where I can download a package from the internet using curl through a proxy server using the command

`curl -x http://<proxy_host>:<proxy_port> --proxy-user <proxy_user>:<proxy_user_password> -L http://rpmfind.net/linux/dag/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/dag/RPMS/<package>.rpm -o <package>.rpm`

But if I set the proxy with the command:

`setenv HTTP_PROXY http://<proxy_user>:<proxy_user_password>@<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>`

and then I try to get the package with the command:

`curl -O http://rpmfind.net/linux/dag/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/dag/RPMS/package.rpm -o package.rpm`

it doesn't work, it just return time out after a long time. My intention is to provide to that server access to the internet outside the internal network and I'm using curl to test this.

The OS is RedHat 6.9 and the shell that I'm using is '/bin/tcsh'.

What I'm doing wrong in this case?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

curl only supports the `http_proxy` environment variable for setting the proxy for HTTP with the environment. Lowercase being the key and vital difference.

curl does not acknowledge the uppercase version of that variable for security purposes: that variable can be set by an incoming request in a CGI environment.

Comment: This is weird - I have 10 servers with only `HTTP_PROXY` set and curl works fine. On one server however, same OS, same curl version, it only works with `http_proxy`. On none of the servers is `http_proxy` set.